# How to resize image before uploading to CDN using CURL

Tags: php, image, curl, image-processing

I have to two different domain, one is for `CDN` and the other for my application, am trying to upload image from `example1` to `cdn.example 2` using `CURL`, it is working perfectly well but my problem is to resize the image to get the dimension i want before saving it. I don't know if this will be done on the user site or the CDN site and i also don't know how i can resize it as it was read before posed. I have a function to resize image after it has been uploaded but i never trying while uploading can someone help me please

**example.com/upload.php**

```
<?php 
$image_file = (isset($_FILES['Image']) ? $_FILES['Image'] : null);
if(!empty($image_file)){
  $filename = $image_file['tmp_name'];
  $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
  $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
  $post_var  = array(
      'image' => base64_encode($data),
      'id' => 100
  );
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cdn.example.com/saveimage.php');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . upload_cdn_server_key));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_var);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $out = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  curl_close ($curl);
  $pms = json_decode($out,true);
  $url= $pms['data']['link'];
     if(!empty($url)){
        $image_uploaded = true;
     }
}
```

**cdn.example.com/saveimage.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["image"], $_POST["id"])){
 $encoded_file = $_POST['image'];
 $productid = $_POST['id'];
 $filepath = __DIR__ . '/image/gallery/p/'; 
 $filename = md5($productid.date('Y-m-d H:m:s i')).'-1.jpeg';
 $uploadeImage = file_put_contents($filepath.$filename, $decoded_file);
}
```

Comment: Why not use pass-through origin pull, then you just resize the image on save, upon first hit/cdn fetch remove the asset

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i really don't understand what you mean, can you please assist me

Comment: Bit old but something like, https://github.com/lcherone/SimplePOPCDN - have a normal site, then just change the url, the CDN pulls from your site and caches it.. then you dont have to push changes you just delete the cache.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone am still confused about that script and how it works

Comment: Heres a picture: https://www.nczonline.net/images/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/cdn2.png

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you, i will use this when i advance me php skill and also understand how to implement it so it will be useful